# Did the ancient Greeks know that $\pi$ was not the root of some polynomial?

Tags: real-analysis, abstract-algebra, soft-question, math-history

Did the ancient Greeks know that $\pi$ was not algebraic ( did they know it was not the root of some polynomial? )

If not could they have possibly deduced such a thing with their level of understanding of mathematics? (what I mean in conjecture it)

I realize this may be considered off topic but i think its an interesting intellectual exercise. I realize they couldn't have easily proved such a result as it took us forever whilst trying to prove it but many conjectures have a solid basis for themselves with no proof could they have been inclined to believe such a result?

Comment: Did the Greeks know that what is polynomial?

Comment: $p(x) = x-\pi$.

Comment: Since it got an upvote i feel i should explain for those that do not understand what an algebraic number is. It is a number that is the root of a polynomial with integer coefficients. so you know $\pi$ is not an integer.

Comment: Beckmann's "A History of $\pi$" has nothing relevant, unfortunately.

Comment: The comment of @Nosrati is definitive. The Greeks did not have algebra in the sense that a modern high-school student understands. I gather (eager to be contradicted here) that they didn’t even have the concept of a fourth power. If you square a number, that automatically relates it to an area, and you just don’t multiply numbers willy-nilly.

Comment: i have to assume he meant did the Greeks even know what a polynomial is?

Comment: Of course, for the Greeks, a polynomial would start with $\pi$.  https://el.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Πολυώνυμο

Comment: @Lubin Interesting.  There are lots of squares and cubes in physics but few higher powers.  I can only think of the Stefan Boltzmann law; it has a fourth power.

Comment: The irrationality of $\sqrt 2$ was traumatic enough.

Comment: I'm sure some Greeks must have read Lindemann's 1882 paper in which he proved the transcendence of $\pi.$

Comment: @bof Yeah, perhaps "ancient Greeks" would be more appropiate.

Comment: They were aware of irrational numbers, at least.

Comment: Better suited for https://hsm.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @Lubin Euclid's proof of the existence of infinitely many primes involves taking the product of an unknown number of integers. While there would be no fourth powers in that product, perhaps that notion wasn't that foreign to mathematicians of Euclid's time.  What historians seem to agree upon is that ancient Greek algebra, in so far as it could be called "algebra," had a strong geometric slant.

Comment: Even the irrationality of $\pi$ was unknown until $1761$, when Lambert proved it.

Comment: The ancients couldn't possibly have "known" that $\pi$ is transcendental, if by "know" you mean "be in possession of a proof." But I suspect much more is true, that they didn't even have the concepts of algebraic versus transcendental.

Comment: It was already a great achievement of Archimedes to squeeze the value of $\pi$.

Comment: @copper.hat "They were aware of irrational numbers, at least." That's really not so clear.  It's commonly said that Euclid or Pythagoras or someone proved that $\sqrt 2$ is irrational. But at the most what they actually proved is that there does not exist a rational $r$ with $r^2=2$; the idea that they had a notion of "number" that included $\sqrt 2$ is at least problematic, if not simply false.

Comment: Sorry, @FabioSomenzi, but as I understand the history, Euclid’s proof **does not** involve multiplying many primes together, but rather taking their least common multiple. You and I know, with our modern wisdom, that in the case of primes, the two results are the same. But conceptually, they are completely different.

Comment: @Lubin Good point about the least common multiple.  From propositions 16 and 19 I get the impression that Euclid fully understood that the LCM of prime numbers is their product, though he thought of lengths measuring other lengths where we think of integers dividing other integers.  I'm no historian, though, and you may well be rigth.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich: I believe that the Elements mentions incommensurable lengths; not quite irrationals, but seems credible that they realised the world was not entirely rational.

Comment: The Elements includes a bunch of material about "numbers in continued proportion" which is essentially about geometric sequences. For example, [IX.35](https://mathcs.clarku.edu/~djoyce/elements/bookIX/propIX35.html) gives the sum of a geometric series. This is certainly enough to formulate the idea that $\pi$ is transcendental, as long as you're willing to believe that there is a pair of segments whose ratio is $\pi$ (which Archimedes certainly was, though Euclid may not have been). Whether or not this would have been considered an interesting statement is another question entirely...